# Visual Studio 2019 during publish getting fxcop is hung or deadlock error

Tags: visual-studio, deadlock, fxcop

I am trying to publish my web application in visual studio 2019 and during the publish getting the below fxcop error.

"MSbuild error CA 0001 - Fxcop is hung or deadlocked".

How to fix this error ? Please help.